# Am I using .is() correctly to access an element's ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

This is part of a weather App I've been reworking and now I want to add the forecast for the next 5 days as well. I've written in comments what I'm trying to accomplish and I feel like I'm on the right track, but am unsure if I'm using Jquery's .is() method correctly

Link to JSON example: https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast

```
$.getJSON(api, (data) => {
// console.log(data);
const weekly_forecast = data.daily.data;

    $("#currentTemp").append("<h4 id='tempData'>Currently<br> "+data.currently.temperature+"</h4>");
    $("#currentConditions").append("<h4>Conditions<br>"+data.currently.summary +"</h4>");
    $("#percipitationChance").append("<h4> Chance of Percipitation<br> " + data.currently.precipProbability +"%" + "</h4>");
            //  $("#reveal").on('click',() => { //click button
            //data.main.tempData //on click convert temperature to farenheight
            //  });
        $("#weekly_forecast div").each( () => { //loop through each div within weekly forecast
            const i = 1;                       //Intialize counter starting at 1, we already have day[0] displayed in current data
            while (i < 5) {                   //While my counter is less than 5 -> (for the next 5 days of the week)
                $(this).is(('#day_'+i)() => {   //Target the referenced element (current div in iterration)
                                                    //Append the inner html to reflect JSON data for day[i];
            });
            i++;                            //Add 1 to i and loop again unless i = 5
        }           
    });
});
```

Accompanying HTML:

```
    <!--Weekley Forecast-->
        <div class="flex-container" id="weekly_forecast">
            <div class="day" id="day_1">
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="day" id="day_2">
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="day" id="day_3">
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="day" id="day_4">
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="day" id="day_5">
                <h2></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Ended up using this for-loop for my solution

```
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) { //loop over the object's next 5 days
                    const weekly_forecast = data.daily.data;
                    $('#day_'+[i]).append("<h3>"+weekly_forecast[i].apparentTemperatureMax + "<br></h3><P>" + weekly_forecast[i].summary + "</p>");
                }
```

Comment: Almost, `.is()` returns a boolean. You need to check `if ($(this).is('#day_" + i)) { /* then do stuff */ }`

Comment: @deweyredman What are you talking about? The selectors will be `"#day_1", "#day_2", etc.`

Comment: actually, nevermind, I misspoke.

Comment: somethign just seems a bit off...

Comment: found it:  he declares i as a const, but tries to increment it...this code should throw an error? no?

Comment: What I actually want to do is match the number; aka [i] , within the id of the current irreration and match it to an array value within a JSON file

Comment: @deweyredman I believe you're actually right about my increment, but I still think based on what mhodges said I;m using .is() wrong

Comment: can you show us your html? that might help.

Comment: If i'm looking at this correctly, you really only need a for loop like this:
`for (var i = 1; i <6; i++) {
   $('#day_'+i).append(whatever)
}`...or am i missing something?

Comment: @deweyredman that was my original plan, but thought this might be a solution for shortening the code

Comment: I believe your way is a bit longer? you have no need to target the the weekly forecast divs when all you want are the inner day divs, right?

Comment: I don't really understand this code. What do you need `.is()` for, exactly?

Comment: @deweyredman exactly and match that same [i] to the corresponding object in my JSON at that index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you need to use "is", as you're only targeting the inner div ids:

```
$.getJSON(api, (data) => {
    // console.log(data);
    const weekly_forecast = data.daily.data;

        $("#currentTemp").append("<h4 id='tempData'>Currently<br> "+data.currently.temperature+"</h4>");
        $("#currentConditions").append("<h4>Conditions<br>"+data.currently.summary +"</h4>");
        $("#percipitationChance").append("<h4> Chance of Percipitation<br> " + data.currently.precipProbability +"%" + "</h4>");
                //  $("#reveal").on('click',() => { //click button
                //data.main.tempData //on click convert temperature to farenheight
                //  });
        for (var i = 1; i <6; i++) {
         $('#day_'+i).append(data[i]) // data[i] or data.forecast[i] or whatever you have your forecast data stored in your JSON
        }

    });
```